# SimpleCov ignoring the app folder

Tags: ruby, simplecov

I have a simple Ruby app with the following structure

```
root
|___ app
      |___ a.rb
      |___ b.rb
      |___ z.rb
|___ spec
      |___ app
            |___ a_spec.rb
            |___ b_spec.rb
            |___ z_spec.rb
      |___ tasks
            |___ atask_spec.rb
      |___ spec_helper.rb
|____ tasks
      |___ atask.rake
```

I'd like to check code coverage using simplecov so I have added the gem to my Gemfile and the following  code to my spec helper

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter '/spec/'
end
```

But, when I run all my specs (`bin/rspec spec`) SimpleCov considers only the code in `tasks/atask.rake`.

I have also checked `SimpleCov.root` and it returns correctly the root.
Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you include simplecov gem to your Gemfile with `require: false`? Do you `require 'simplecove'` _at the very top_ of your spec_helper.rb?

Comment: Yes to both questions (see spec helper above). As mentioned the coverage runs and gives me the result. The problem is that is not considering the app folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561242/simplecov-report-ignores-folders-in-app-directory